# How to pass a mathematical operation (such as +, -, *, /) as an argument to a method

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a Reverse Polish Notation (RPN) calculator which, until now, looks like this:

```
class RPNCalculator
  attr_accessor :numbers, :value
  def initialize
    @numbers = []
    @value = nil
  end

  def push(number)
    @numbers.push(number)
  end

  def plus
    if value.nil?
      number1=@numbers.pop
      number2=@numbers.pop
      @value = number1 + number2
    else
      @value += @numbers.pop
    end
  end

  # minus_proc = Proc.new {|a,b| a - b}

  def minus
    number1=@numbers.pop
    number2=@numbers.pop
    @value = number2 - number1
    # operate_on_two_numbers(minus_proc)
  end

  def operate_on_two_numbers(&prc)
    number1=@numbers.pop
    number2=@numbers.pop
    @value = prc.call(number1,number2)
  end

end
```

For example, the following commands

```
calculator=RPNCalculator.new
calculator.push(5)
calculator.push(8)
calculator.plus
p calculator.value
```

produce the number "13".

This is how it's supposed to work, but there seems to be a lot of repetition in the code. For example, the "plus" and "minus" functions are largely the same; only a "+" and "-" inside the code differs.

I'd like to try to define a (private) method which accepts as an argument an operation which operates on two numbers, such as "+", "-", "*", or "/". It would be nice to use 'shortcut notation' like the shortcut `.inject(:+)`.

I've given it a try with the commented-out lines and the method `operate_on_two_numbers`, but when I comment in the lines I get an error "undefined local variable or method 'minus_proc'".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use tags in the title unless they're part of the natural flow of the sentence. SO uses the tags you set for indexing, and they're honored by the search engines.

Comment: Math operators are *already* methods, so in one sense, it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use any [arithmetic operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) here in the same manner

```
def operate_on_two_numbers(a, b, op)
  a.send(op, b)
end

operate_on_two_numbers(1, 2, :+)
#=> 3
operate_on_two_numbers(1, 2, :-)
#=> -1
```

Here's what your full code could look like

```
class RPNCalculator
  attr_accessor :numbers, :value
  def initialize
    @numbers = []
    @value = nil
  end

  def push(number)
    @numbers.push(number)
  end

  def plus
    operate_on_two_numbers(:+)
  end

  def minus
    operate_on_two_numbers(:-)
  end

  private

  def operate_on_two_numbers(op)
    number1=@numbers.pop
    number2=@numbers.pop
    @value = number1.send(op, number2)
  end
end

calculator=RPNCalculator.new
#=> #<RPNCalculator:0x00000002efe460 @numbers=[], @value=nil>
calculator.push(5)
#=> [5]
calculator.push(8)
#=> [5, 8]
calculator.plus
#=> 13
calculator.value
#=> 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'll accept the ".send" method as what I was looking for initially, in the end I used a method which accepts a block as an argument, because for division (the "divide" method) I required some more operations (namely, converting to float prior to division). The updated RPN calculator is shown below.

```
class RPNCalculator
  attr_accessor :numbers, :value
  def initialize
    @numbers = []
    @value = nil
  end

  def push(number)
    @numbers.push(number)
  end

  def plus
    operate_on_two_numbers {|a,b| a + b}
  end

  def minus
    operate_on_two_numbers {|a,b| b - a}
  end

  def times
    operate_on_two_numbers {|a,b| a * b}
  end

  def divide
    operate_on_two_numbers {|a,b| Float(b)/Float(a)}
  end

private

  def operate_on_two_numbers(&prc)
    if @numbers.empty?
      raise "calculator is empty"
    else
      number1=@numbers.pop
      if @value.nil?
        number2=@numbers.pop
        @value = prc.call(number1,number2)
      else
        @value = prc.call(number1,@value)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Note that "plus", "minus", etc. are now one-line methods, and much of the complexity has been moved into the private "operate_on_two_numbers" method.